# Something like Windows Phone Store Test Kit for Android and Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, windows-phone-store

I am developing an Android app and I want to publish my App on Google Play. I have seen the Android documentation and found this:

- **[Core App Quality](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/core.html)**
- **[Launch Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html)**
- **[Upload applications](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en)**

No one of the links above says something about Google rejecting an app, so where I know, Google is more flexible on this point.

In case of Windows Phone apps, there is the **Windows Phone Store Test Kit for Windows Phone 8** that provides a suite of automated and manual tests to help prepare apps to be accepted in the Windows Phone Store the first time one submits them.

- **[Windows Phone Store Test Kit for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394032(v=vs.105).aspx)**

I want to know if there is something like this for Android and also need to know if Google makes a test like this before accepting the app on the store. And what considers Google to accept the app or not.

Any help on this I will really appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I can say you that Google makes test only to find hazard and viruses, but not if your app is pretty or working great.

Also, an Android app is usually approved in some hours, so it is really fast if something goes wrong.

Ow, and for testing you can use Unity test or monkey test, which are easily implemented and used in the platform.